# Moment.min.js this.format is not a funtion

Tags: javascript, momentjs, x-editable

I am trying to use a combodate in xeditable however, when I try to save moment.min.js says that this.format is not a function. This is coming from somewhere in moment.js so here is my code:

```
$('#start').editable({
  viewformat: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  success: function(result, newValue){
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/Project/Edit',
      data: { id: '1', NewValue: newValue, type: 'StartDate' },
      success: function (result) {
        if (result.Success == 'Success') {
          notify('The Start Date was successfully updated.', 'success');
        } else {
          notify('The Start Date could not be updated at this time.', 'error');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}).on('hidden', function () { 
  $(this).parent().next().children().removeClass('disabled');
});
```

Here is the line that is called in moment.js

```
toString: function () { return this.format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ")
```

This line in moment.js is called right after the editable success function is called.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm. You are saying this.format() is not a function, but nothing formats a date in your code. Maybe you should breath in, breath out, concentrate on your question, breath in, breath out, and show the code that causes the issue

Comment: It looks like the error is not coming from this part of the code. Please look at the stack trace and show us the code that triggers the error.

Comment: Right, as I said the error is coming from WITHIN moment.js:


moment.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: this.format is not a function

Comment: But it is not triggered by this code. This code does not call anything related to Moment so there is no way for anyone (that does not have access to your source code) to even take an educated guess as to why you are experiencing that error. Update the question with the parts that relate to moment.js

Comment: Well its triggering somehow. I put the line that gets triggered from my success: funtion(result, newValue) line above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to call the .format() method on newValue in the ajax call. That's how moment js was giving me that error. Here is the working code:

```
$('#start').editable({
  viewformat: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  success: function(result, newValue){
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/Project/Edit',
      data: { id: '1', NewValue: newValue.format('MM/DD/YYYY'), type: 'StartDate' },
      success: function (result) {
        if (result.Success == 'Success') {
          notify('The Start Date was successfully updated.', 'success');
        } else {
          notify('The Start Date could not be updated at this time.', 'error');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}).on('hidden', function () { 
  $(this).parent().next().children().removeClass('disabled');
});
```